# How to update Room database in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my application I want use **MVI** for application architecture and I should use **Room database**.
I have one `activity` and one `fragment`!
In fragment I receive data from user and save into database and in activity show this data into recyclerview.
I write below codes and my data successfully save into database!
**But** for show it into activity, I should exit from application and enter to show data list!
I want without exit from application, update automatically this list.
**Dao codes :**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_table")
fun getAllData(): MutableList<Entity>
```

**Repository codes:**

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(private val dao: DataDao) {
    fun allData() = dao.getAllData()
}
```

**ViewModel codes:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: MyRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val mainIntent = Channel<MainIntent>()
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<MainState>(MainState.Idle)
    val state : StateFlow<MainState> get() = _state

    init {
        handleIntent()
    }

    private fun handleIntent() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mainIntent.consumeAsFlow().collect{
                when(it){
                    is MainIntent.LoadAllData-> fetchingAllDataList()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fetchingAllDataList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = MainState.LoadData(repository.allData())
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity codes :**

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    //Send
    viewModel.mainIntent.send(MainIntent.LoadAllData)
    //Get
    viewModel.state.collect { state ->
        when (state) {
            is MainState.Idle -> {}
            is MainState.LoadData -> {
                dataAdapter.setData(state.list)
                fataList.apply {
                    layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
                    adapter = noteAdapter
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several methods below can solve this problem.

1. Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Send an EventBus message after saving data to database in fragment and handle this message in `MyViewModel` or your Activity to reload data
2. In your 'dao' interface, change function return type to `LiveData`: `fun getAllData(): LiveData<MutableList<Entity>>`. When related data changed in database, Room database automaticly notify changes to `Observers`. Check [this](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-4-saving-user-data/lesson-10-storing-data-with-room/10-1-c-room-livedata-viewmodel/10-1-c-room-livedata-viewmodel.html)
3. Use [`Broadcast`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) like using `EventBus`
4. If fragment is contained in the `Activity` which requires the notification when data changed, use [`SharedViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing) to notify activity.

```
class MyFragment: BottomDialogSheetFragment {
    var entityChangeListener: IEntityChangeListener? = null
    ...
    // after saving data to database
    entityChangeListener?.onChanged()
}

class MyActivity {
    fun showDialog() {
        val fragment = MyFragment()
        fragment.entityChangeListener = object : IEntityChangeListener {
            override fun onChanged() {
                // change [fetchAllDataList] function to public
                myViewModel.fetchAllDataList()
            }
        }
    }
}

interface IEntityChangeListener {
    fun onChanged()
}
```

```
// using SharedViewModel
class MyFragment: BottomDialogSheetFragment {
    var entityViewModel by sharedViewModel<EntityViewModel>
    ...
    // saving entity data
    entityViewModel.saveData(entities)
}

class MyActivity {
    // shared view model for entity database business
    val entityViewModel by viewModels<EntityViewModel>
    // viewmodel for other business logic
    val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>

}

class EntityViewModel: ViewModel(){
    ...
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<MainState>(MainState.Idle)
    val state : StateFlow<MainState> get() = _state

    fun fetchingAllDataList() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _state.value = MainState.LoadData(repository.allData())
        }
    }

    fun saveData(entities: List<Entity>) {
        dao.save(entities)
        fetchingAllDataList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. Can you help me with method 4 ? For show fragment I used BottomDialogSheetFragment . In activity I have a button and when click on this button show my fragment . I know if I used EventBus or LiveData my problem is fixed! but I don't want use this. can you help me with **SharedViewModel** ? please

Comment: @Dr.KeyOk If you show fragment in activity, you can just  add an `ChangedListener` param in fragment to notify acitivty reloading. See answer above, i will add code snap to show how to use this way

Comment: How can I auto update list just with **StateFlow** ?

Comment: @Dr.KeyOk I updated my answer, you can check it.